# Suggestions for how to communicate from JS running in a UIWebView to the hosting obj-c app?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I plan to have a shell iphone app with a uiwebview, with the bulk of my application running through javascript in the uiwebview.

Now i know it's easy to communicate from the obj-c environment to the javascript environment by using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, however is there a good recommended way of communicating from the javascript environment to the obj-c world?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I always use an approach in which the app "navigates" to a special URL:

```
window.location = "myapp://somemessage/someargument";
```

And where the app catches this in the following function:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
                shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    if ( [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"myapp"] )
    {
        [self handleJSEvent:url];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Furthermore, depending on what you need, you could use some kind of event queue which you fetch using `JSON.stringify(events)`, in response to a message sent to the app using the method described above. For communicating from app to js JSON is also very suitable.

If there is a standard or a standard way to do this, I clearly missed it.

Comment: From my googling, i think you have described the common 'standard', if you will. Great!

Comment: You're welcome. Other than my gut feeling told me, this approach is quite reliable as well.

Comment: Thanks so much. Good to know that this is reliable too, thats important.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very nice method to call javascript inside of UIWebView:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"yourJSFunction('some_data');"];
```

call backs are best done as mentioned by MVDS through the Url:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Answer (score 2):

I just created a library that will facilitate this communication for you largely using the method described by mvds and Ondrej. Includes two-way communication, jQuery event-style, with optional JSON payloads with multiple listeners. Check it out: https://github.com/tcoulter/jockeyjs

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by changing the url hash?

Comment: Do you mean the blah.com/something.html#HASH ? I've noticed that approach, does that involve catching the shouldStartLoadWithRequest event?